# Generating Unique Receipt Codes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Hello in my **laravel** application I have a function that generates a unique receipt code whenever a customer completes a transaction.

This is the format of the code:
1. 4 Digit Identifier of Store eg. **ABCD**
2. Type or Category of item purchased. eg. **E** for electronics, **T** for toys
3. Special secret two digit code eg. can be between **01** and **10**.
4. Date in really short format. eg. **31J16** for 31st January, 2016
5. Four digit code for customers to use for support issues or returning an item. eg. **3267**.  This is randomly generated.

So a sample would look like this: **ABCDT0131J163267**
Total length is 16 characters.

Now what I want to do is each time a code is generated make sure it does not already exist in my database if yes then it should generate a new one and so on till it comes up with a unique code.

Now my issue is getting an **efficient** solution t generate unique codes that won't end up looping soo many times like I intend on doing.

Comment: What's your question? We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Thank you sir, I am aware of that.  My question as stated is a way to do this **efficiently** while avoiding looping multple times and performing database calls on each loop to check if a code exists or not and generating a new one if it exists.

Comment: You're going to have to make database calls. The chances of it having to loop depend on the size of your four digit code and the number of orders you have in an average day. If you want it to loop less, increase the length of that code so you're less likely to have collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I thought of something that will have me make only a single database call in the first loop.   I get all the existing codes from the database into a list then I use the function `in_array()` to check the list, if it exists it generates a new code.

Only drawback will be if a transaction is made after the list has been generated that specific code will not be a part of the list.